# How to establish a button function to my boolfield

Tags: python, django, django-models

''i want to add functionality to my Publish button in HTML. i have made a method under my Post(model) and made a view for that button with a url. i dont know why my button fuctn is not working.
''

My Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def publish(self):
        self.published=True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My Views.py

```
@login_required
def publish_button(request,pk):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk)
   post.publish()
   return redirect('blog_detail',pk=post.pk)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('comment/<int:pk>/', comment_post, name='comment_form'),
    path('publish/',PublicList.as_view(),name='publish'),
    path('publish/<int:pk>/',publish_button,name='p_button'),
    path('', index, name='indexpage'),
 ]
```

My html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block content %}
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Blog Details:</h1>
  <hr>
 <div class="jumbotron">
 <h3 align = 'center'>{{ detail.title }}</h3>
 <hr>
  <div class="mb-5">
    <h4>{{ detail.description }}</h4>
  </div>
 <p>Posted By: {{ detail.user }}<span class="ml-5">{{ detail.created_on  }} </span><br>                                      
</div>


  {{ detail.pk }}
    <a href="{% url 'p_button' pk=detail.pk %}">Publish</a>


<p></p>
<h6>Wanna add comment? <span class="ml-3">
  <a href="{% url 'comment_form' pk=detail.pk %}">
    <input class="btn btn-dark" type="button" name="" value="Comment">
  </a></span>
</h6>
<hr>
<h4>Comments:-</h4>
<hr>
{% for comment in detail.comments.all %}
<h5>{{comment.text}}</h5>
<p>by: @{{comment.author}}<span class='ml-5'>{{comment.commented_on}}   </span></p>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

TraceBack:
    File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv \lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
```

126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
```

124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
```

21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\Desktop\Django\prac_18\firstapp\views.py" in publish_button
```

71.     post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
```

93.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
```

390.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
```

844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
```

862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
```

1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
```

1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

```
File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
```

1161.         arg, value = filter_expr

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /publish/5/
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: Not working how? What happens?

Comment: its showing :--  TypeError at /publish/5/

cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: updated all tracebacks

Comment: Thanx for the response sir, but i found my error , i forgot to add the request pk to my pk argument of get_object_or_404

Comment: post = get_object_or_404(Post , pk = pk)

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` takes a filter expression, exactly as if you were calling Products.objects.get()`. So it should be:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
```

Comment: sir what are the objects.fllter(args). what args can be used, i want to collect my Post objects which got boolean true in a different Blog page

Comment: can i use something like........ return  Post.objects.filter(Post.published==True).all()